# Connect Bookmark to another

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, bookmarks

I have word file with VBA userform with one ComboBox1, In ComboBox1 I wrote this code for three options

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ComboBox1.List = Array("Mr.", "Ms.", "Miss")

End Sub
```

and I have 2 Bookmarks with name Bookmark1 and Bookmark

I wrote code

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim Bookmark1 As Range
 Set Bookmark1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
 Bookmark1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
 End Sub
```

The ComboBox1 is connected to the Bookmark1 (Whatever my choice from ComboBox will appear in Bookmark1).
What I want is when Bookmark1 = "Mr." then Bookmark2 should be changed to "Manger" , and if choose  "Mis." should be Changed to "student", and if choose  "Miss." should be Changed to "Job seeker"

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: Using ActiveX controls means that your form will not work on a Mac. You could do this with Content Controls and have it usable on a Mac.

Comment: I want is when Bookmark1 = "Mr." then Bookmark2 should be changed to "Manger" , and if choose "Mis." should be Changed to "student", and if choose "Miss." should be Changed to "Job seeker"

Comment: You need to add code to `CommandButton1_Click` which checks `ComboBox1.Value` and then sets the text at the second bookmark.

Comment: can you help me with code?

Comment: You already know how to set the bookmark text and retrieve the value of the combo box. You just need to write an `If` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing a Case statement.

The code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Bookmark1 As Range
Dim Bookmark2 As Range

Set Bookmark1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
Bookmark1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Set Bookmark2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range
Bookmark2.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Select Case Bookmark1
  Case "Mr": Bookmark2.Text = "Manger"
  Case "Mis": Bookmark2.Text = "student"
  Case "Miss": Bookmark2.Text = "Job seeker"
 
End Select
 
End Sub
```